# What was the most distant supernova spotted by a amateur astronomer until today?

Tags: astronomy, telescopes, supernova

What type of commercial amateur telescope and what method (*difference imaging*,...) did he use for identifying the supernova?

Answer (score 1):

This source [here](http://sallyhanreck.com/archives/2560) has an example at 290,000,000 - 300,000,000 light years, although it's a bit thin on detail, and can't really be considered an authoritative source. (Also [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-1318457/Astronomer-Dave-Grennan-discovers-290million-year-old-supernova-exploding-star-garden-shed.html).)